# Undefined index -> PHP Upload not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

PHP Upload:

> Notice: Undefined index: file in

On line: `$count = count($_FILES['file']['name']);`

Run almost every code i found with this error...still didn't got any results

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
if(isset($_POST['uploadFinish']))  { 
    $bcode = $_POST['code'];
    $newpath = "upload/".$bcode."/";
    if (!file_exists($newpath)) {
        mkdir($newpath, 0755, true);
    }
    $count = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
    if($count < 1) { 
        $message = "At least 1 file required"; $count='';
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $newpath.'/File-'.$bcode);
    }
}
?>
```

HTML/JS:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btntrg123" id="uploadBtn" style="background: #008489; border-color: #008489">Upload file</button> 
<form style="display: none!important;" id="uploadConf" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div style='height: 0px;width:0px; overflow:hidden;'>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" onclick="getFile()" class="btn btn-primary inptri123">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="<?php echo $code; ?>">
    <input name="uploadFinish" value="1" type="hidden"> 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".btntrg123").click(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".inptri123").trigger('click');
}); 
function getFile(){ 
    document.getElementById("file").onchange = function () {
        var file = this.value;
        console.log(file);
        var form = document.getElementById('uploadConf');
        form.submit();
    };
}
</script>
```

Both code is same php file. Running the php from other file, same result.

Console.log gives me the file, but it's not uploaded to the server.
Folder is created.

Comment: `$_FILES['file']` it will be array

Comment: _Small Point_ If your code is readable (nicely formatted) there is just the chance that it is also debuggable

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);` to check what it actually contains.

Comment: var_dump($_FILES); => array(0) { }

Comment: I don't see any ajax request or `action` at your form.

Comment: Move the php code to upload.php, added action="upload.php" to form. Same result.

Comment: Ok, do you have errors turned on? Seems files are not accepted for some reason, should be in the logs.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: file is the only thing that is in the logs...Added error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); Nothing pops up

Comment: Try uploading a very small file (like 10kb) and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

i think you wanted check number of files uploaded.

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btntrg123" id="uploadBtn" style="background: #008489; border-color: #008489">Upload file</button> 
<form action="upload.php" style="display: none!important;" id="uploadConf" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div style='height: 0px;width:0px; overflow:hidden;'>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" onclick="getFile()" class="btn btn-primary inptri123">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="0">
    <input name="uploadFinish" value="1" type="hidden"> 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".btntrg123").click(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".inptri123").trigger('click');
}); 
function getFile(){ 
    document.getElementById("file").onchange = function () {
        var file = this.value;
        console.log(file);
        var form = document.getElementById('uploadConf');
        form.submit();
    };
}
</script>
```

try this

```
    <?php
$count = 0;
if(isset($_POST['uploadFinish']))  { 
    $bcode = $_POST['code'];
    $newpath = "upload/".$bcode."/";
    echo $newpath;
    if (!file_exists($newpath)) {
        mkdir($newpath, 0755, true);
    }
    $count = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
    if($count < 1) { 
        $message = "At least 1 file required"; $count='';
    } else {
        $total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
        for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $newpath.'/File-'.$bcode.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

1. Added the action attribute to form.

> action ="upload.php"

2. Made slight changes in the PHP code to handle the upload.

Comment: Same: Notice: Undefined index: file on $count line

Comment: can you replace php with this code and check <?php echo count($_FILES['file']['name']); ?>

Comment: After upload returns 0. This means that somehow the file is not submitted in the form. Could be because of how the buttons work and how form is submitted?

Comment: might be the reason, let me check

Comment: with the new code it returns me the $newpath value when i upload. Just the plain text: upload/code

Comment: didn't get it, file doen't upload?

Comment: it's returning $newpath since  echo $newpath; command, it's throwing any error ? ideally it should have uplodated to the webserver\upload\$bcode\ file. i have tested the code, it's working fine...

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/_gQ6VN5v86sySG-w595fSg -> upload the code here

Comment: Just now saw the echo in code...the error is still the same on first $count. Dir is created, but file not uploaded....

Comment: can you post the workable code in https://paiza.io/projects/_gQ6VN5v86sySG-w595fSg here. i have tested the same code in my system. it's works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When multi file upload you can use

```
$name=$_FILES['file']['name'][$index];

$tmp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$index];
```

Your code should as below

```
$total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {


  $tmp= $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

  if (!(empty($tmp )){

    $path= "/upload/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];


    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path)) {

         echo $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]. ' uploaded';
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file on the line with if(count($_FILES['file']['name']))

Comment: @Laurenti you still get undefined index file on the line with !

Comment: Do you have upload folder in not haven't create upload folder Manually

Comment: Yes, i got PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file on $total (1 time), then like 1000 same notice for $tmp inside for :)

Comment: Uploading a 13kb img

Comment: Try without js.with submit input ,look at the error ?

Comment: Also remove cache of browser

Comment: Sometimes can't seen your changes suddenly,try rkve cache of browser

Comment: The folder is created through php: if (!file_exists($newpath)) {
        mkdir($newpath, 0755, true);
    }

Comment: Maybe cant find path ,are you sure ? Is form submit the files ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you simply missed an form `action`.

It should be something like:

```html
<form style="display: none!important;" id="uploadConf" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/your/api/call">
```

Or, you can attach an event for the form using `javascript`:

```
function processForm(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();

    /* do what you want with the form */

    // You must return false to prevent the default form behavior
    return false;
}

var form = document.getElementById('uploadConf');
if (form.attachEvent) {
    form.attachEvent("submit", processForm);
} else {
    form.addEventListener("submit", processForm);
}
```

Comment: Submitting the form:        var form = document.getElementById('uploadConf');
        form.submit();

Comment: You just `submit` it, but form without an `action` or `event` will do nothing (just reload the page in some browsers). You need to say, what file or action on the server should be executed.

Comment: I send uploadFinish with value 1 when the form is submitted. The php (in my logic..i'm kinda beginner) catches is, then execute the code. Moved the php to a file, and put the action="upload.php" to the form and added submit input that is triggered in the getFile(remove the form.submit() ), i get the same notice.

Comment: @LaurentiuLomnasan check your network tab of the browser using dev tools. Are files submited?

Comment: I see the file there (initiator upload.php) status 200.

Comment: @LaurentiuLomnasan check exactly form parameters. Status 200 gives nothing here.